# call method in form from usercontrol

Tags: c#, forms, user-controls

In usercontrol I have some objects(`textbox`,`combobox`,etc) . In the form,I have a button that shows or hide some objects from usercontrol. I am trying to call the method from usercontrol but it doesn't work. My code:

usercontrol:

```
public void MinimMaxim()
{
    _txtName.Visible = true;
    _txtPackage.Visible = true;
    _panelButton.Visible = false;
    _txtBody.Visible = false;
    _btnPlus.Visible = false;
}
```

and in form:

```
//method that creates taskcontrols at every button click
private void _buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TaskControl task= new TaskControl();
}
//call function from usercontrol
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    task.MinimMaxim = true;
}
```

Comment: `MinimMaxim` is a function or property of you usercontrol?

Comment: Does this code compiled without error?

Comment: No. It says that task is not in the current context and also it doesn't recognize MinimMaxim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had try Freelancer's answer and it's worked.

User Control class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF_15631067
{
    public partial class UserControl1 
        : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void MinimMaxim()
    {
        _txtName.Visible = true;
        _txtPackage.Visible = true;
        _panelButton.Visible = false;
        _txtBody.Visible = false;
        _btnPlus.Visible = false;
    } 
}
```

}

Form class

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF_15631067
{
    public partial class Form1 
: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl11.MinimMaxim();
    }
}
```

}

if we create this UserControl on runtime the answer is;

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SOF_15631067
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        **Controls.Add(uc1);**
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uc1.MinimMaxim();
        // userControl11.MinimMaxim();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

call method by refering following code through user control>>

```
yourUserControlName.methodName();
```

**I think in your case it may be :**

```
yourUserControlName.MinimMaxim();
```

Answer (score 3):

task variable that you create is a local variable to _buttonAdd_Click method. It cannot be accessed from any other method. It has to be a member variable if you want it to be used from other methods.

Comment: How can I make it a member variable? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

To access controls in user control, I normally expose some properties of that control and from the main page I can use properties to play with control.